# How to use 2 routers in one house/network

Tags: networking, router

I have two Huawei HG633 routers and I currently only have one connected. I would like to use the other one as a "wifi extender" or just to share the connection im aware i simple cannot just plug it in as you can only have one adsl modem. (BTW i cannot connect the two routers together physically.)

SO how do go about doing this (in depth explanation please)

Comment: Why can't you connect them together?

Comment: @JuliePelletier I want the second router to act as a WiFi extender. Without using any wires between them

Comment: That is not possible on the same band.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to buy a Access Point and connect it to your Router. 
They are cheap and are already enough for home enviroment.

Otherwise you can change your IP configuration on the one router. Make a Uplink to the other one. Change gateway to internal use.

Comment: so i read online disable dhcp and then forward the ip address to the first router. but if i disable dhcp im told to use static. do i need to change the static settings? or literally change the second router from dhcp to static and then just forward? 

"Make a Uplink to the other one. Change gateway to internal use." how do i do this?

Comment: I don't know your router. But in most cases you can configure the interfaces.  
You have 4 interfaces. On should be connected to each router. Assume Port2 with port 2 an the second one. Give Port2 on Router 1 (connected to wan) a static ip. exapmle 172.16.18.1. Now configure the second port to another IP on the same net. Example 172.16.18.100.
http://routersetup.blogspot.co.at/2007/08/connecting-two-routers-wired.html maybe this link helps.

Comment: but the routers obviously have to be physically connected then?